# insert into table as select * from table does not work

Tags: php, mysql

This SQL statement is used in PHP:

```
Insert into Table from AS Select * from Tabl1 where id='5'
```

Any clues to why it is not inserting values from Table1 to Table?  User executes this statement to create a copy.

Comment: Where did you read that this was valid syntax?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth No where, but can I do it? I can do the same in Oracle, wy not in mysql.  If wrong syntax, what is the correct one.

Comment: The correct syntax is, of course, [explained in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the "FROM AS" and it should work.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html

Answer (score 2):

Remove `from as`:

`Insert into Table (Select * from Tabl1 where id='5')`

(and BTW why `'5'` and not just `5`? Is `id` actually a string value?)